# Why does SimpleITK crash during ResampleImageFilter execution?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, simpleitk

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I try to change the voxel spacing of a 3D image like in this [example](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/123390/SimpleITK.ResampleImageFilter). The image is pretty large with around 500x500x300 voxels and uses around 100MB. When the line `resampler.Execute()` is reached the shell stops executing the python3 script. I think this is because of a lack of memory, but which memory? Harddisk? RAM? Does anyone know why this might happen and if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You're running out of RAM.  You volume is 75 million voxels, but that resampling example code is using 32-bit floating point numbers.  So that's 300 megabytes of memory.  And then there's memory of the output volume.  So who knows how much memory you're needing in total.

Try setting the output pixel type to something smaller, like a signed short or an unsigned char.

Comment: I changed the output pixel type to uint8 but it still crashes. How can I get the used memory of an sitk image? When I convert it to numpy with ```image = numpy.uint8(image)``` and get the memory used in bytes by ```image.nbytes``` it returns 49283072 bytes which is less than 50MB... This does not seem too much to me...

Comment: You can figure out the memory size of an image with the following methods: GetNumberOfPixels, GetNumberOfComponentsPerPixel, and GetSizeOfPixelComponent.  Multiply the results of those 3 together to get the number of bytes.